# Incrementally build up object to satisfy type

Tags: typescript

I am building an application where I have some state that is altered by mutators. Consuming code should not have direct access to the state, but only a context where the mutators have been massaged via a curry so that the consuming code needs only to invoke a partially applied function.

So instead of the consumer invoking:

```
setCount(state: State, firstArg: number, secondArg: number);
```

the consumer should invoke:

```
setCount(firstArg: number, secondArg: number)
```

To that end, I have the following:

```
  interface State {
    count: number;
  }

  const state: State = {
    count: 0
  };

  interface IMutators {
    setCount: (state: State, firstArg: number, secondArg: number) => Partial<State>;
  }

  const mutators: IMutators = {
    setCount: (state: State, firstArg: number, secondArg: number) => ({
      count: state.count + x + y
    })
  };

  type RemoveStateParam<T extends any[]> = ((...x: T) => {}) extends ((
    h: State,
    ...t: infer R
  ) => {})
    ? R
    : never;

  type MutatorsWithoutState<M> = {
    [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any
      ? (...args: RemoveStateParam<Parameters<M[P]>>) => Partial<State>
      : never
  };

  type MutatorsInterface = MutatorsWithoutState<IMutators>;

  interface Context {
    mutators: MutatorsInterface;
  }

  const buildInterfaceFromImplementation = (
    mutators: IMutators,
    state: State
  ): MutatorsInterface => {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(mutators).forEach(k => {
      const mutator = mutators[k];
      const curried = _.curry(mutator, 1);
      const interfaceCompliantMutator = curried(state);
      newObj[k] = interfaceCompliantMutator;
    });

    return newObj as MutatorsInterface;
  };

  const context: Context = {
    mutators: buildInterfaceFromImplementation(mutators, state)
  };

  context.mutators.setCount(1, 2);
```

What I would like to improve is the `buildInterfaceFromImplementation` method:

```
const newObj = {};
Object.keys(mutators).forEach(k => {
    const mutator = mutators[k];
    ...
});

 return newObj as MutatorsInterface;
```

Is there some way I can get away from using the cast on the last line? I'd like to type `newObj` like:

```
const newObj: MutatorsInterface = {}; // This obviously won't work
```

Comment: Probably need an assertion somewhere... you can `return newObj as MutatorsInterface` as you're doing, or you can do `const newObj = {} as MutatorsInterface`, which won't be true until after you call your setters.

Comment: You probably want something like [lazy object initialization](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28503) but TS doesn't support it.